# What is the use case difference between forced quorum and force cluster to start without quorum?

Tags: sql-server, clustering, sql-server-2019, failover-cluster-instance

I'm learning about handling fci issues and stuck at 2 concepts to recover from cluster failure:

1. Forced quorum
2. Force start without quorum

What is the factor to decide whether to use which of the above?

For example does forced quorum also mean manual forced failover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: [WSFC Disaster Recovery through Forced Quorum (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/wsfc-disaster-recovery-through-forced-quorum-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

**What is the factor to decide whether to use which of the above?**

The two options you mentioned above are not two distinct options that you can choose from.

'Force start without quorum' is one of the steps (second to be precise) of recovery from a quorum failure.

When do you use force quorum:

> Remember that quorum failure will cause all clustered services, SQL
> Server instances, and Always On availability groups, in the WSFC
> cluster to be set offline, because the cluster, as configured, cannot
> ensure node-level fault tolerance. A quorum failure means that healthy
> voting nodes in the WSFC cluster no longer satisfy the quorum model.
> Some nodes may have failed completely, and some may have just shut
> down the WSFC service and are otherwise healthy, except for the loss
> of the ability to communicate with a quorum.

Another condition is `a healthy quorum existed before the quorum failure`.

**For example does forced quorum also mean manual forced failover?**

You cannot perform a manual forced failover during a quorum failure.